# php line Smarty template engine reverse stristr

Tags: php, smarty

I want to edit my php template, but I can not get it right.
I use the the Smarty template engine.

My default php line looks like this:

```
{$childItem->getLabel()}
```

That does display HTML like this:

```
MY TEXT - MY SUB TEXT
```

I want to remove all content before the `-`. So that it only displays the `MY SUB TEXT` part.

I tried this, but that does not work, because that removes the content after the sign:

```
{$childItem->getLabel()|stristr:'-' : true}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional "true" parameter you're passing to `stristr` refers to **$before_needle**, so you'll get back the portion of the string before the hyphen. Unfortunately, removing that will get you back the portion of the string after **and including** the hyphen, i.e. "- MY SUB TEXT".

A clean solution would be to use `explode`, and then use the second element of the resulting array, like this:

```
{assign var="splitItem" value=" - "|explode:$childItem->getLabel()}
{$splitItem[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for php documentation for [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php):

> If TRUE, stristr() returns the part of the haystack before the first
>   occurrence of the needle (excluding needle).

however, as the normal behaviour of the function is to include the needle and the text after it and that's not exactly what you want, you'll also have to remove it with *replace*, so:

```
{$childItem->getLabel()|stristr:'-'|replace:'-':''}
```